# Why doesn't my background turn red in this simple CSS?

Tags: html, css

#### HTML

```
<div class="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <p>More lorem.</p>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.main {
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    background: red;
    clear: both;
}

.footer ul {
    float: right;
}

.footer li {
    display: inline;
}

.footer p {
    float: left;
}​
```

Also [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZs92/1/).

I've simplified a larger version of my main website not working. My footer won't change colour. See how it says red?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/uZs92/2/

Add

```
.footer {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

When you have floating elements inside the container, you can:

- Add `overflow:hidden` (or something different than `visible`) to the container -> http://jsfiddle.net/uZs92/2/
- Add an element with `clear:both` at the end of the container (instead to the container itself) -> http://jsfiddle.net/uZs92/6/
- Add `:after,::after{content:'.';font-size:0;}` to the container -> http://jsfiddle.net/uZs92/5/

Answer (score 2):

The footer does turn red, but since all of it's content is floating, it has nothing inside it that will prevent its height from being `0`.

Set `overflow: hidden` on it so that floating elements will influence its height.

Comment: Answer first, *then* demo...sigh. May I offer you an otherwise redundant [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uZs92/3/)?